# How to group tiles in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, next.js

I'm new to canvas Please Help. I have a canvas like in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg7VZ.png). All these are tile maps
I followed [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps/Square_tilemaps_implementation:_Static_maps) to paint the tile on the canvas.

I want to achieve like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPJXg.png). How do I get the group of tiles of same color?

I created a function to know which tile is clicked. I get (col , row)
and I also want to get the size of the tile like 1 * 1 or 3 * 3 and so on.

In Canvas.js Getting Coordinates and handling click event

```
  function getCoords(e) {
    const { x, y } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = e.clientX - x;
    const mouseY = e.clientY - y;
    return [Math.floor(mouseX / 32) + 1, Math.floor(mouseY / 32) + 1];
  }

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(getCoords(event));
  };
  // some more stuff
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...rest} onMouseDown={handleClick} />;
```

In index.js

```
  <main className={styles.main}>
    <div className={styles.tileset_container_selection}></div>
    <div className={styles.canvasContainer}>
      <Canvas draw={draw} />
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: canvas is just a flat (2d) bunch of dots basically so if you want to change it other than overlaying something you'll find yourself having to redraw the whole thing. So, could you describe how you are saving the tiles and also what exactly you want to do on 'focussing' an area.

Comment: @AHaworth I edited the question, please do check. Thanks in advance.